# Rails 6.1 webpacker reduce unused JavaScript

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, tailwind-css, webpacker, ruby-on-rails-6.1

I have a rails 6.1 app using webpacker and tailwind.
My page load speed test shows a bad loading speed and suggests to "Reduce unused JavaScript". Sidenote: it also suggests to "Reduce unused CSS". So purge seems not to work. But on the page where I perform the page load speed test, the chartkick/chart.js is not even used. So it seems like it is loading every JS library, despite it is not even used on a page.

Here is my packs/application.js file:

```
// This file is automatically compiled by Webpack, along with any other files
// present in this directory. You're encouraged to place your actual application logic in
// a relevant structure within app/javascript and only use these pack files to reference
// that code so it'll be compiled.

import Rails from "@rails/ujs"
import Turbolinks from "turbolinks"
import * as ActiveStorage from "@rails/activestorage"
import "channels"
import "chartkick/chart.js"
import ahoy from "ahoy.js"
import { initMapbox } from '../packs/init_mapbox'

require("stylesheets/application.scss")
require("../stylesheets/components/pagination.scss")
require("../stylesheets/components/vacancy_description.scss")


Rails.start()
Turbolinks.start()
ActiveStorage.start()

document.addEventListener('turbolinks:load', () => {
  initMapbox();
})
```

Here is my tailwind.config.js file:

```
const colors = require('tailwindcss/colors')

module.exports = {
  purge: {
    enabled: process.env.NODE_ENV === "production"
    content: ['./app/views/**/*.html.erb', './app/javascript/**/*.js',],
  },

  darkMode: false, // or 'media' or 'class'
  theme: {
    colors: {
      transparent: 'transparent',
      current: 'currentColor',
      black: colors.black,
      white: colors.white,
      gray: colors.trueGray,
      indigo: colors.indigo,
      red: colors.rose,
      yellow: colors.amber,
      green: colors.emerald
    },
    extend: {},
  },
  variants: {
    extend: {},
  },
  plugins: [],
}
```

Hope someone can help!

Comment: The whole point of the assets pipeline / webpacker is that it concenates your JS/CSS into a single file to reduce the number of HTTP requests needed to load the page. Clients have traditionally had a limited amount of simultaineus connections which means that loading multiple files is often a bigger performance hit then loading a bit more code then needed.

Comment: Rails has no idea about which frontend code you need where in your application. While you could potentially split your code into multiple packs you still need to manually figure out what is needed where and the performance gains might not be worth it compared to other efforts. With some larger libs like mapbox it might make sense though.

Comment: There are some newer technologies that kind of challenge this practice though. HTTP/2 allows multiplexing which allows multiple downloads on the same connection - enabling it on your server is a big performance boost. Modern browsers also support the deferred attribute on script tags which lazy load ES6 modules on demand. When it comes to popular libraries like jQuery or Google analytics it's often an advantage to use a popular CDN instead of installing them through yarn and packaging them with your JS as there is a chance that the browser already has the file cached.